# How to compare the values of different objects of an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[In the image `CDH0000403` object should move to GMV1 and `CDH0000405` to GMV2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhkVH.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhkVH.png)

```
[{cNo: "CDH0000403", contractLineItemSelectionChecked: true, companyCode: "1360", profitCenter: "DHA1", approverId: "C7937"},
 {cNo: "CDH0000404", contractLineItemSelectionChecked: false, companyCode: "1360", profitCenter: "DHA1", approverId: "C7937"},
 {cNo: "CDH0000405", contractLineItemSelectionChecked: true, companyCode: "1360", profitCenter: "DHA1", approverId: "C7937"}]
```

What I want to do is first to check  **contractLineItemSelectionChecked** status, if the status is true need to check they have different **contract id** and need to push different contract id objects different places

```
currentState.forEach((el, i) => {
   if ( el.contractLineItemSelectionChecked) {
      push(currentState[i]);
   }
}
```

I tried this but not working

Comment: What does `push` do?

Comment: not working because ? there is no check on `different contract id` in your current loop. And what does `push` do ?

Comment: `push` is a function to move the object to a table

Comment: Where are you pushing the contractId? I mean to which object.

Comment: I have a table with fields `contract no` , `company code` etc , if I select any contract `contractLineItemSelectionChecked` will becomes true , If more than one `contractLineItemSelectionChecked` are true , different contract numbers move to different tables

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter` function for what you need

```js
currentState.filter(element => element.status && push(element))
```

It checks it the `status` is true and then it calls the `push` function

If you want to create an array you only with the desired object

```js
const results = currentState.filter(el=> el.contractLineItemSelectionChecked);
```

Documentation for the filter function [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Thanks for response , what I need is if that results had two objects with two different contract numbers, need to push one object one table and another object to second table

Comment: And if you had 3 obj with 3 different cNo like the one in the example what happens then?

Comment: For example if I have 4 objects and in that for 3 objects `contractLineItemSelectionChecked` is true , I need to move 3 objects to 3 tables

Comment: That logic should be done in your `push` function and not here. I cannot help you with that. The code above sends the entire `object` to your push function. What the `push` function does that's another question in hand. Create another question if you need help there. But as for this, it does answer your original question